# Why do I get cannot load such file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to use the ffi gem to access native extensions.
When I require 'ffi' in a simple ruby script, then it works fine. But when I require ffi in my Rails application, then I get: **cannot load such file -- ffi** Why?

gem env shows this:

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/adminuser/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:

    - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
    - /home/adminuser/.gem/ruby/1.9.1

Comment: Is the gem installed in bundler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ffi'
```

Next:

```
$ bundle install
```

Now:

```
require 'ffi'
```

You need to specify which gem you are going to use in your Gemfile in order to make it available for your Rails project with bundler.

**UPDATE**: I'd encourage you to checkout [How does bundler bundle](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/9/24/how-does-bundler-bundle), [how bundler require gems](http://kerdany.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/how-does-bundler-do-its-magic/), and this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler?view=asciicast).

Comment: Ok, but why? Why is a ruby script able to load the gem and Rails is not?

Comment: I think I found the answer in your second link: "In order to prevent `Kernel#require` from looking further in the other installed gems, Bundler also disables the patched `Kernel#require` by reverting to the original implementation."
Right?

Comment: Bundler restrict the gems and their versions to the mentioned list defined in the Gemfile, which is yes, restricting `Kernel#require` for looking further other than the provided scope of gems. Did it help you?